# How dynamically change UITableViewCell size for the last cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a UITableView with 16-20 cells inside with dynamic cell size. When a cell expands it self it should also move itself to the top of the screen. I did that using "UITableView setContentOffset" method. It works well except for the last cell in table, it's not able to move itself to the top.

I tried altering the frame & content size of UITableView but none of those were working for me!

Any Idea?

[UPDATE]
Here is a part of code: (it's inside the UITableViewCell, so self is pointing to current cell)

```
HomeViewController *tempViewController = (HomeViewController *) delegate;
UIView *commentField;

/*Skipping lines of codes manipulating commentField */

//Adding a subview to current cell which needs more space
[self addSubview:commentField]; 

//Expanding cellSize to EXPANDED_CELL_HEIGHT
//ViewController has access to cell size property and using that to determine each cell size. 
[self setCellSize:(EXPANDED_CELL_HEIGHT)]; 

//Reloading UITableView to reflect the cell size change with animation
[[tempViewController tableView] beginUpdates];
[[tempViewController tableView] endUpdates];

[[tempViewController tableView] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.frame.origin.y) animated:YES];
```

and in my view controller (as I said earlier) I'm getting cellSize form cell itself

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [(BaseTableViewCell *)[cellContainer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] cellSize];
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code. It's really shots in the dark otherwise...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the height of the cell using the tableview delegate method `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` When indexPath.row equals your last row, return the height you would like.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row == i)//i being whatever row index you want to change
    {
      return 60.0;//or float size you want
    }
    else
    {
     return 30.0;
    }
}
```

Or you can just modify the bounds of the cell inside `willDisplayCell:`. If your using a custom tableview cell, just shrink the subviews to whatever frame you'd like and make the cell background clear etc.

Comment: i gave you an example of what to do

Comment: !! Why mine is not right? I'm setting CellSize in the cell    [self setCellSize:(EXPANDED_CELL_HEIGHT)]; then I'm reading it from that heightforRow method.

Comment: It properly size the last cell, but it couldn't move it to the top!

Comment: Dude theres different tableView methods to take care of that..That method gets called for every single cell in your tableview..you cant just return it for one single cell...Look at the tableView delegate methods, theres better options to handle reordering

Comment: This is the method you should use - (void)moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath

Comment: Why should I move cell to another path?

Comment: Whatttt are you talking about? If you want to "move it to the top", just change the indexPath

Comment: Oh, I think here is the confusion! by moving to the top I mean moving the UITableView to the top by setting contentOffset! I don't want to move cells around. (and I cannot change the order of those as well)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29396/discussion-between-ttarules-and-mojtaba)